# ReactJS - Using setInterval for decreasing timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, use-state

I am trying to create a timer application in react. The app works by calling a setInterval timer when the user clicks a button.

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(1500)    // 25 minutes
const [start, setStart] = useState(false)

const onClick = () => {
    if (!start) {
        var tick = setInterval(() => {
            setStart(true)
            if (timer < 0) {
                clearInterval(tick)
            }
            setTimer(timer => timer - 1)
            console.log(timer)
            
        }, 1000)
    }
}
```

Even though the timer is decreasing every second, `console.log(timer)` still prints out 1500 and does not decrease. I am not able to stop the timer thereafter.

Comment: Hi, shouldn't you be passing setTime(timer-1000) instead of `timer=>timer-1000`?

Comment: The re-rendering does not work when that happens. This article explains it https://itnext.io/how-to-work-with-intervals-in-react-hooks-f29892d650f2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` function is asynchronous, so the `console.log` does not have the new value yet.

Put the log inside the function `setTimer`:

```
...
setTimer(timer => {
    console.log(timer - 1)
    return timer - 1;
})
...
```